# Sort or order items with multiple relationships in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using multiple relationship and uses `eager loading`. What I have now are three tables (`quizzes`, `multiple_choice`, `question_numbers`), and I want to sort the `multiple_choice` using the `question_numbers` table with the field `question_number`. How can I do that? Please see my code below:

```
    $undeleted = function($query){
        return $query->where('deleted', 0);
    };

    $quiz = Quiz::with([
        'multiple_choices.question_numbers' => $undeleted
    ])->find($id);


    $quiz_items = collect($quiz->multiple_choices);
    //$quiz_items = $quiz_items->sortBy('question_number');
```

I tried the commented part, but nothings happen.

**Update with dd()**

After I used `dd()`, the result is:

```
Collection {#478 ▼
  #items: array:13 [▼
    0 => MultipleChoice {#427 ▼
      #table: "multiple_choice"
      #fillable: array:6 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "My name"
        "question" => "the question body"
        "created_at" => "2017-06-06 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2017-10-07 18:34:36"
      ]
      #original: array:13 [▶]
      #relations: array:2 [▶]
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update2**

```
 #relations: array:2 [▼
    "pivot" => Pivot {#426 ▶}
    "question_numbers" => Collection {#452 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Quiz {#449 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**Update 3**
*databases*

`quizzes` — `id`, `name`, `body`
`multiple_choice` — `id`, `name`, `question`
`multiple_choice_quiz` — `id`, `multiple_choice_id`, `quiz_id`
`question_numbers` — `id`, `quiz_id`, `question_id`, `question_number`

The `question_number` field in the `question_numbers` table is the field that I want to sort or order.

Comment: I got an error **BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81: Method orderBy does not exist**.

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: Hi Oluwafeni! No there's no question_number field in the multiple_choice, but in the `question_numbers` table, it has.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Please see my update

Comment: No. I used `many to many` relationship. What do you mean question?

Comment: multiple_choice has only `question` field.

Comment: No. Multiple choice is exactly the question. What I want to `sort` is the `question_number` field in the `question_numbers` table. `question_numbers` table has `question_id` there which is the `multiple_choice`'s id.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Please see my update